# Starting with an empty list, I need two threads running at the same time to insert 1 million random integers each on the same list in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linked-list, pthreads

Starting with an empty list, I need two threads running at the same time to insert 1 million random integers each on the same list in C. I am trying to pass the empty list to a thread being created. The function does not seem to recognize the previously created list. I believe it is because I am passing it wrong. The error is as follows:

error: ‘my_list’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘va_list’?
  List_Insert(&my_list, 32);

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//basic node structure
typedef struct __node_t {
    int     key;
    struct __node_t     *next;
} node_t;

//basic list structure (one used per list)
typedef struct __list_t {
    node_t      *head;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} list_t;


void List_Init(list_t *L) {
    L->head = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&L->lock, NULL);
}

int List_Insert(list_t *L, int key) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&L->lock);
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
        return -1; //fail
    }
    new->key = key;
    new->next = L->head;
    L->head = new;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
    return 0;  //success
}

int List_Lookup(list_t *L, int key) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&L->lock);
    node_t *curr = L->head;
    while (curr) {
        if (curr->key == key) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
            return 0; //success
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
    return -1; //failure
}

//Ensures function executes after main
void *myThread(void *vargp) __attribute__((destructor));

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

//Define an empty list
list_t my_list;

//Initialize the list
List_Init(&my_list);

//Create the threads
int i;
pthread_t tid;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, (void *)&my_list);

pthread_exit(NULL);
return 0;

}

//Function to be executed by both threads
void *myThread(void *vargp)
{
    ////FUNCTION NOT RECOGNIZING PREVIOUSLY CREATED LIST////
    printf("Inserting into list\n");
    List_Insert(&my_list, 32);

}
```

Comment: `my_list` is local to `main`, not the the `myThread` function.

Comment: Do _not_ add `__attribute__((destructor))` to `myThread`. `myThread` is only started by `pthread_create`. Adding the attribute will cause bad problems later. Do _not_ do `pthread_exit` in `main`, only in the thread function. You need `main` to loop on `pthread_join` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `my_list` in the thread function. Once you passed `my_list` from main, you can access it through the local variable `vargp` (which is what "my_list" now)

So you might be interested in:

```
void *myThread(void *vargp)
{
    printf("Inserting into list\n");
    List_Insert(vargp, 32);
    return NULL; // see man pthread_create
}
```

But...this is wrong. Because `my_list` is a local variable (local to `main`). So once you exit the main thread, you can no longer access "my_list". So either you'll have to wait for the threads to complete with `pthread_join()` calls for the two threads )For that, you'd need to save `pthread_t` ids of each thread - currently you're overwriting the thread ids).

Or you'd have to allocate it with:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    //Define an empty list
    list_t *my_list = malloc(sizeof *my_list);

    //Initialize the list
    List_Init(my_list);

    //Create the threads
    int i;
    pthread_t tid;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, my_list);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
```

}

which you can `free()` later. Then you'd be able to use `myThread` as above.

You have other problems:

- The `destructor` attribute will make the `myThread` be called again at the end. This is almost certainly not what you want. You probably want the thread to carry on while the main thread exits. For that, calling `pthread_exit()` as currently do is sufficient. So simply remove this attribute `__attribute__((destructor))` from the function prototype.
- You should avoid using identifier with `__` as they're reserved names.
- Your thread function should return a pointer (as required by `pthread_create` API).

Answer (score 1):

Well, `my_list` is a variable declared inside the `main`'s scope. So it is not visible inside `myThread` function. You can simply achieve this by using your `vargp` argument:

```c
void *myThread(void *vargp)
{
    list_t *my_list = (list_t *)vargp;
    printf("Inserting into list\n");
    List_Insert(my_list, 32);
    // Notice the missing & in the call!
}
```

Another problem is that the list is allocated inside the `main()` function's stack frame. That means that after main returns, that stack frame is no longer accessible and you will have undefined behaviour. You have 2 options here:

1. Either allocate your list on heap using `malloc`
2. Wait for all the threads inside the `main` function, so the stack frame of `main` stays alive while your threads use that list.

Comment: None of you are wrong :). Indeed, the C standard library will terminate the process once the `main()` returns. But in this case the `main()` never returns as @usr stated, but rather exits the current thread.

Comment: @usr, Touché. I shouldn't have dropped a comment about a design pattern that I don't actively use. I'll delete it.